# MATLAB: How to loop through each (x,y) pair in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, loops, for-loop

So I want to create a loop in MATLAB where I can retrieve the x,y pairs.

So far, I have two arrays:

```
x = [x1 x2 x2 x1 x1];
y = [y1 y1 y2 y2 y1];
```

I would like to create a for loop where I can retrieve pairs (x1,y1), then (x2, y1), then (x2, y2), (x1, y2), and lastly (x1,y1) once again.

Comment: Start [here](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/loop-control-statements.html)

Answer (score 1):

This is a trivial loop:

```
x = [x1 x2 x2 x1 x1];
y = [y1 y1 y2 y2 y1];
for index = 1:numel(x)
   pair = [ x(index), y(index) ];
end
```

Answer (score 0):

In Matlab it is great to be able to avoid loops.

You can build a matrix from your two vectors:

```
xy = [x;y];
```

Now every column of xy is a pair.  You can then do:

```
for col_index = 1 : size(xy,2)
    xy(:, col_index)  % whatever you want to do here
end
```